How does the Kalman Filter incorporate unseen states during measurement?
I'm curious how/if the kalman filter is able to infer states which aren't directly measurable during the measurement process.
Suppose our system has states $(x_t, v_t)$ representing position and velocity. Suppose our motion model is $x_{t+1} = f(x_t) =  x_t + v_t*\Delta t, v_{t+1} = v_t + a_t*\Delta t$ where $a_t$ is our control input and suppose we can measure only position, that is $h(x_t, v_t) = x_t$
What I'm wondering is, how can we infer information on $v_{t+1}$ through the measurement step? If a motion model is used we can make a guess on velocity(which I suppose is the first step) but the measurement has to propagate information back to the velocity estimate eventually(IE, our velocity estimation can't diverge as if it did the position estimation would not be correct).
So what is going on?

I think it is somewhat more intuitive to think about it in terms of markov chain and bayesian filtering. Working out the Kalman filter equations from the Bayesian filtering equations certainly adds a lot of intuition.

You can just think about it intuitively. Let's say that initially my guess for the velocity is 0 m/s at $t = 0$, and we get a measurement that the position $x=0$ at that time. The filter would guess that at $t=1$ the position is again $x=0$. We then get a measurement that $x = 5$. So the filter (depending on the initial covariance on the velocity) will update its estimate to be closer to 5 m/s.
Basically, since the filter knows how the object is moving, it can back out what the velocity must have been.
I can modify my answer to include more of the math, if you would like. The super brief version is that the prediction step (which incorporates the motion model) would introduce covariance between the position state and the velocity state. The position state was measured to be higher than expected, so the filter suspects that the velocity was higher than expected as well.

You can think of it as the measurement interesting with  the covariance state of the filter.
Consider a simple example -- you start with an unknown velocity and you travel at constant velocity for one second.
The model doesn't tell you where you are or how fast you're going, but it does tell you exactly how the new position and that constant velocity are related.
So, when you measure position, that relationship -- which is represented by the covariance matrix -- turns the position measurement into a guess of the starting velocity. If you didn't have the model and resulting covariance matrix, you could just as easily guess that you teleported.
